# Issue using Angular Dart material-input with type=number

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I am trying to build a web app (essentially an online store) with Angular Dart using elements from materialDirectives for building the elements of the app. Right now I'm working on the back-end which will work with the inventory database and such. However I think either there's a problem with the package or I'm doing something wrong. Not sure which, probably me doing something wrong though, since it works okay on the [online demo](https://dart-lang.github.io/angular_components_example/#/material_input). I've looked over the source code of the demo and can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong.

So, the issue is, when I run the program, I get the following error `Type 'double' is not a subtype of type 'String'`. This error appears both on loading the page when the program populates it with the existing items in the database, as well as when I attempt to change the value of price, cost, or stock. I also notice that the labels and leading text do not appear on any of the inputs except 'name' unless price, cost, and stock are all null. It seems to me Angular is choking up on the numerical inputs because it expects a string, despite the fact that I have explicitly specified `type="number"`.

The code that appears to be related to the issue is as follows.

In the html template for the component:

```
<material-expansionpanel-set *ngIf="!products.isEmpty">
  <material-expansionpanel *ngFor='let product of products'
    expandIcon="edit" [alwaysHideExpandIcon]="true"
    [hideExpandedHeader]="true" name='{{product.name}}'>

      <material-input floatingLabel label="Name"
        [(ngModel)]='product.name'></material-input>

      <material-input floatingLabel label="Price"
        type='number' step='0.01' checkPositive leadingText='$'
        errorMsg="Enter a valid price" [(ngModel)]='product.price'></material-input>

      <!-- ... Some similar stuff cut out here so the post wasn't a mile long ... -->

  </material-expansionpanel>
</material-expansionpanel-set>
```

And the code for the product class:

```
class Product{
  final int id;
  String name;
  String description;
  double cost;
  double price;
  int stock;
  Category category;

  Product(this.id, this.name, {this.price, this.cost, this.stock, this.category, this.description});
}
```

The products array that the template is looping through is just an array of Product objects. Right now the list is hard-coded into the program though as development goes on obviously it will fetch it from the server.

So, how can I tell it to actually expect a number? Is there a switch or something I have to set that I'm missing? Everything seems to work fine without the numerical inputs.

Comment: What Dart and Angular version are you using?

Comment: Dart 1.24.3,  angular 4.0.0+2 with angular_components 0.8.0

Comment: I think there was a change recently related to your question. You could check the commits in angular_components, but if it's actually related, I'm sure it's only for Angular 5. As workaround you could parse the string yourself with `num.parse(...)`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Angular 5 is still in Alpha though, isn't it?

Comment: That's because it Depends on Dart which is not released. I think you'd be better off using Angular 5 than Angular 4, probably even more stable.

Comment: Okay, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Even though it's in alpha, it's production ready, it being alpha just means that the api may change in the future, but there are no problems with stability or performance.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else facing this same issue, it was 100% resolved by upgrading to Angular 5 as per the suggestions I received in the comments. Not the answer I was hoping for because it required a lot of code refactoring to update to Angular 5, but I was early enough in development of this project it was manageable. I notice that the example code in the online demo I had been following was also built using Angular 5, so is seems to me that non-text `<material-input>` just wasn't developed in Angular 4. Someone smarter may have a better answer but this worked for me. Hopefully it helps someone else!